# Showing time span for less than an hour

Tags: c#

Other than using a ternary operator, how would I show an expected time format for following case:

```
given:
0:59:00

expected:
59:00
```

In other words, if time span is less than an hour don't show leading 0 and colon.

```
//currently handled this way:
time.hours > 0 ? time.ToString("h\\:mm\\:ss") : time.ToString("mm\\:ss");
```

Comment: What's wrong with the ternary?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't. There's no custom format specifier for this. If you do this a lot a custom extension method over `TimeSpan` would not go amiss, of course.

Comment: There are [Standard TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) which omit the *number of days* if they are not needed, but, alas, there is none which does the same for the *number of hours*. You can condense your ternary to `time.ToString((time.Hours > 0 ? "h\\:" : "") + "mm\\:ss");`, but I don't think you can get more terse than that.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, just wanted to get a different perspective. Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, if you change it to `(time.TotalHours >= 1 ? ((int)time.TotalHours).ToString() + ":" : "") + time.ToString("mm\\:ss")`, it also works for timespans spanning more than 24 hours.

Comment: Conditionally building the format string is far less readable than the expression in the question, albeit more concise.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this. Personally, I'd swap just the format string, rather than the whole `ToString()` call, but that's entirely my choice.